# Nested lists and saving into a text file

Tags: python, arrays, save

I have a nested list containing strings and integers that I'm trying to save into a txt file but I'm having trouble with formatting.

```
array = [(string1, int1),(string2, int2),(string3, int3),...(string_n, int_n)]
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(repr(array))
```

and get the array saved as is.

How do I format the output so that the format is as below instead of the array as is?

```
string1 int1
string2 int2
.
.
.
string_n int_n
```

This is propably a very newbie question, but I couldn't find anything similar with search...

Answer (score 2):

```
for s, i in array:
    f.write('{} {}\n'.format(s, i))
```

The `\n` is needed since `write` does not include a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
array = [('s1', 1),('s2', 2)]

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in array:
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(*item))
```

**Output:**

```
s1 1
s2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join` instead

```
for sub_array in array:
     f.write(' '.join(sub_array) + '\n')
```

This will work for arbitrary length arrays.

If you have a list of lists rather than an array of mix types then you would need to coerce the elements to string before using the join (as pointed out by @Blckknght).

This could look like this

```
for sub_array in array:
     f.write(' '.join(map(str,sub_array)) + '\n')
```

Comment: Its worth noting that this only works if the inner sequences contain only strings. If you have integers in them, you need to convert them to strings at some point before `join` gets them (e.g. with `map(str, sub_array)`, perhaps).

Comment: @Blckknght you are right but if you create an array with mixed types such as `[(string, int),...]' then the int is coerced to a string so the sub_array will always be string. If however, the OP had a list of lists then you are correct. Cheers for the comment.

Comment: Your edit looks good, and will work with any kind of types in the inner sequence. I'm not sure I understand your comment though. The inner sequences shown in the question are a tuples, which can contain objects of any kind of mixed types you want. The questioner's use of the term "array" is perhaps misleading. I strongly doubt they're using a fixed-type sequence like a `numpy` array.

Comment: Ah you are correct - Thank you for your comments! Yes, I was talking about `numpy` arrays, looking again you were correct once more!

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy savetxt method:

```
import numpy as np 
np.savetxt("output.txt", array, fmt="%s", encoding="utf-8")
```